# Calculating $\int e^{-|x|} \, dx$.

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to calculate
$\int e^{|x|} \, dx$, but merely splitting up in two cases for $x<0$ and $x>0$ does not give the desired result, which I got by calculating it on a CAS. 
Suggestions would be very welcome.

Edit.
I made a mistake. It's $\int e^{-|x|} \, dx$.

Comment: What result are you getting? Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: On my CAS I get some non arbitrary constants - which I find bizarre. I get $e^x$ for $x\leq 0$ and $-e^{-x}+2$ for $x>0$. I don't know where the constant 2 comes from.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, $\int e^{-|x|}dx =1/2 e^{-x} ((e^x-1)^2 (-sgn(x))+2 e^x+e^{2 x}-1)+C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine a primitive $F(x)$ by integrating with a fixed lower bound, say $0$; for $x\ge0$ we have
$$
F(x)=\int_{0}^x e^{-|t|}\,dt=\int_{0}^x e^{-t}\,dt=\Bigl[-e^{-t}\Bigr]_0^x=1-e^{-x}
$$
For $x\le0$ we have
$$
F(x)=\int_{0}^x e^{-|t|}\,dt=\int_{0}^x e^{t}\,dt=\Bigl[e^{t}\Bigr]_0^x=e^x-1
$$
Now you can incorporate the arbitrary constant of integration, getting
$$
\begin{cases}
-e^{-x}+1+C & \text{for $x\ge0$}\\
e^x-1+C & \text{for $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
which can also be written, since $C$ is arbitrary,
$$
\begin{cases}
-e^{-x}+C & \text{for $x\ge0$}\\
e^x-2+C & \text{for $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 7):

Using $$\exp(|x|) =\begin{cases} \exp(x) & x \geqslant 0 \\ \exp(-x) & x < 0 \end{cases} $$
we can integrate branch-wise:
$$
   \int \exp(|x|) \mathrm{d}x = \begin{cases} \int \exp(x) \mathrm{d}x & x \geqslant 0 \\ \int \exp(-x) \mathrm{d}x & x < 0 \end{cases} = \begin{cases} \exp(x) + C_1 & x \geqslant 0 \\ -\exp(-x) + C_2 & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$

Comment: The antiderivative of a continuous function should be continuous (even differentiable), so there is a relation between $C_1$ and $C_2$, precisely that $1+C_1=-1+C_2$, so $C_2=C_1+2$.

Comment: egreg - that answerd my question!

Comment: @egreg: The relation between $C_1$ and $C_2$ is included in my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

The primitive that people seem to want to give is
$$
\mathrm{sign}(x)\left(e^{|x|}-1\right)+C
$$
Another way of writing this is
$$
\mathrm{sign}(x)\left(e^{|x|}-1\right)+C=\left\{\begin{array}{}
e^x-1+C&\text{if }x\ge0\\
1-e^{-x}+C&\text{if }x\lt0\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
which is continuous at $x=0$ and whose derivative is $e^{|x|}$ otherwise.

Answer (score -2):

we can also write
$$\int e^{|x|} dx= sign(x) e^{|x|}+C$$

Comment: Compute $\int_{-.001}^{.001}e^{|x|}\,\mathrm{d}x$ using your primitive. Your answer will be about $1000$ times off.